# Can we render a sky layer with transparent layers?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes, transparency

I am using a `transparent` alpha in the shading menu, while rendering my layers, so I can later composite them together.

1. Question is, is there something like a sky layer that would go on the bottom?

Possible fork of this question - 2. is there another way of compositing two layers on top of each other? Can I pull an alpha from a layer with the `transparent` option off?

[image: ad question (1)]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest solution to this is to do a third render without any visible objects and Alpha set to Sky in the shading properties in the render menu. Once that's done, alpha over your sky background just like you have done already between the two scenes.[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is funny. I didn't previously know I could render multiple scenes and combine them. Your answer opened my eyes. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could load in a background image(with the image node) from a separate file to mix in.
[image: mix in a background image]

You can also use the alpha over node to put the image behind(you then have a little more control over premultiply):
[image: alpha over]

Comment: Yes, problem is the perspective wouldn't probably match - more so if it was an animation.

Comment: @Dwelle that's true, but if you have a landscape and you just want a skymap(on the horizon), this works.

Comment: In that case it would indeed be an option.